# joining several tables with different number of rows and different spacing between columns

Tags: r, string, match, lines

I've been trying to join several tables from different files. They look somewhat like this:

```
    x   x
    x    x
    x  x    x

    Profile a b c
    1       0 0 0
    2       0 0 0
    ...
    x   x
    x    xxxxxxx
```

Desired output:

```
    x   x
    x    x
    x  x    x

    Profile a b c
    1       0 0 0
    2       0 0 0
    ...
    x   x
    x    xxxxxxx
    x   x
    x    x
    x  x    x

    Profile a b c
    1       0 0 0
    2       0 0 0
    ...
    x   x
    x    xxxxxxx
```

I've been using the following codeto join my tables (they are in different files), but It only joins the first two tables correctly. I was wondering if there is some way to read the tables separately all at once, with something such as this:
for (i in 1:4){
  strings(i)<-readLines("archive",i,".txt").

I'm using the following code:

```
    strings1<-readLines("C:/data/archive1.txt")
    strings2<-readLines("C:/data/archive2.txt")

    b1<-length(strings1)
    b2<-length(strings2)

    for (i in 1:4){ 
      if (i==1){ 
       a<-strings1 
      }
      else{ 
        c<-b1+length(strings1)
        data<-readLines(paste("archive",i,".txt", sep="")) 
        a[b2:c]<-data
        b1<-c 
        b2<-b1+1 }
    }
```

Is there a way so that don't have to write: string 1, string 2,.... because I have around 200 files.

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: It is not clear what your expected output will be (based on the example lines).  What is `...`?

Comment: I'm just using ... to signal that the table continues with that format. t's just a long table with a format that I have managed to read and save with the same format, it ends with asterisks, and then has text with different formats. I just expect the output to be the table followed and preceded by the text with differing formats. I'm having trouble reading the lines with different formats before the tables, or somehow saving it like so.

Comment: Please update your post with the expected output

Comment: What I currently have are the tables formated correctly, I did that with str_match. What I don't have is the text corresponding to the Xs in my example.

Comment: I don't understand what part of my post I should update, I only need a way to insert the text (those Xs) in between tables...

Comment: Your expected output just like you showed the input dataset

Comment: oh..... my expected output are tables just like that one, one after the other. My expected output is to have them be one after the other, they have different number of rows, though. I think I have already accomplished it.                                                                                     b1<-length(strings1)
b2<-length(strings2)

for (i in 1:4){ 
  if (i==1){ 
    a<-strings1 
  }
  else{ 
    c<-b1+length(strings1)
    datos<-readLines(paste("archivo",i,".txt", sep="")) 
    a[b2:c]<-datos 
    b1<-c 
    b2<-b1+1 }
}

Comment: I'm having trouble with the length of the strings though, all my tables have different number of rows